# Compiling libpurple for Android

Tags: android, compilation, pidgin, libpurple

I want to implement libpurple in android to integrate all the IM chat support to Android application, for that I'm using following links to work with:

[Compiling libpurple on Android](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/GSoC2012/Android/compiling)

Following is the repository for android
[soc.2012.android repository for android]

- (http://hg.pidgin.im/soc/2012/michael/android/)

But problem is that, I have downloaded the full repository but as suggested in Compilation steps, there is no "**android/workspace**" folder downloaded from the server to my PC.

Comment: @gtumca-MAC : First install [Mercurial tool in windows](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) and then run this **"hg clone http://hg.pidgin.im/soc/2012/michael/android/"** command.
It will download all the files from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Android code I run:

```
hg clone https://hg.pidgin.im/soc/2012/michael/android/ android
```

This gets me a copy of the whole repository in the folder android. Then to switch to the Android branch I'll run the command:

```
hg checkout soc.2012.android
```

At which point I can then see the folder with the Android workspace in.